# What is the right place to store persistent app data before exiting?

Tags: android

I have a single `Activity` application with a data container that is populated at the launch of the application from a JSON formatted private text file. When exiting the application, whether it's a graceful exit or forced one, the the data must be written back to the text file.

Android documentation [states](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) that application data shouldn't be saved in the onDestroy method.

I have now overwritten the following methods to make sure the data is stored at exit:

```
protected void onStop() {
    persistenceManager.storeIfChanged();
    super.onStop();
}

protected void onPause() {
    persistenceManager.storeIfChanged();
    super.onPause();
}
```

The `storeIfChanged` methods writes the application data to the text file if it has changed since last save. **My question is**, does this guarantee the application data is saved no matter how the application is terminated (unless it's force majeure). **Secondly**, is it superfluous to do the saving in both onStop and onPause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, saving data in `onPause` is the recommend way. Data will always be saved unless the application is force closed.

Calling it in `onPause` is enough, `onPause` is always called before `onStop`.